# Annotation type vs Annotation (Java)

Tags: java, annotations

What is the real Difference between the Annotation type and the Annotation itself. My teacher told me to solve this, cause he said, that these two are 2 different thing and i better don't mix them up.

Can someone explain it to me? I looked up on the Internet for it, but I found nothing usefull.
I´d really apriciate that.

Thank you. :)

```
@Target(value = ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface DBoperation {

    public enum ParamType { 
         FLOAT, INT, DOUBLE, CHAR, BOOLEAN, LONG, SHORT, BYTE, REFERENCE, NONE
     }

    public enum OperationType {
         CONNECT, DISCONNECT, UPDATE, QUERY, DELETE
     }

     public OperationType typOp() default OperationType.QUERY;
     public ParamType typParam() default ParamType.REFERENCE;
     String description();    
}
```

Comment: Like the difference between a class and an object?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the manifestation of your confusion. In code please? This question is a little unclear.

Comment: If you are implementing an interface with three methods, and you put `@Override` on all of the methods, there are three annotations.  They all refer to the same annotation type, [`java.lang.Override`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Override.html).  See sections 9.6 and 9.7 of the JLS, [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6).

Comment: Ok i think i get it now, So the DBoperation i created is an Annotation Type, yes ? ... and if i Use it on methods in my source code, there will be three different annotations of this annotation type.  Im i right ?

Comment: @MarkedOne Yep, I think you've got it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code sample is the declaration of the annotation type. For every method you annotate with your annotation there will be an annotation containing the data from the annotation.

You can get the annotation using reflection, e.g. like this:

```
Class<?> annotatedClass = // put some class here
int methodIndex = // index of a annotated method
// get the annotation
// dbOperation is the annotation, DBoperation the type
DBoperation dbOperation = annotatedClass.getMethods()[methodIndex].getAnnotation(DBoperation.class);

// get data from the annotation 
String operationDescription = dbOperation.description();
```